# Angular: Height Change Not Detected

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I've written a pair of directives which are designed to zoom one of a number of elements to a larger size when the element is clicked. Clicking the zoomed element should return it to normal size. When an element is zoomed, it's sister elements (they're all d3 charts) are made invisible. They're restored to visibility when the enlarged element is unzoomed.

Here's what the HTML looks like:

```
<chart-container class="chart" chart-height="400" >
    <h3 class="text-center">Vehicles by year</h3>
    <div class="text-center" full-screen-toggle>
        <bar-chart bar-data="{{vehiclesByYear}}"
                    layout="{{vehiclesByYearLayout}}"
                    bar-labels="{$dy: '-.5em', $anchor: 'middle'}"></bar-chart>
    </div>
</chart-container>
<chart-container class="chart" chart-height="400">
    <h3 class="text-center">Vehicle speed distribution</h3>
    <div class="text-center" full-screen-toggle>
        <pie-chart pie-data="{{aboveBelow}}"
                   layout="{{aboveBelowLayout}}"></pie-chart>
    </div>
</chart-container>
```

The magic is in the element directive chart-container and the attribute directive full-screen-toggle. The latter always decorates a child element inside a chart-container. Here's the code for the two directives:

```
angular.module( 'MarkOlbert.fullScreenChart', [] ).directive( 'chartContainer', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            chartHeight: '@chartHeight',
        },
        controller: ['$scope', '$element', '$rootScope', function ( $scope, $element, $rootScope ) {
            var zoomState = 'normal';
            var _self = this;

            this.changing = false;
            this.chartHeight = $scope.chartHeight;

            function unZoom() {
                $element.css('width', '50%' );

                _self.changing = true;
                $rootScope.$broadcast( 'chart:unzoom' );
                _self.changing = false;

                zoomState = 'normal';
            }

            function zoom() {
                $element.css( 'width', '100%' );

                _self.changing = true;
                $rootScope.$broadcast( 'chart:zoom' );
                _self.changing = false;

                zoomState = 'full';
            }

            $element.on( 'click', function () {
                switch ( zoomState ) {
                    case 'normal':
                        zoom();
                        break;

                    case 'full':
                        unZoom();
                        break;
                }
            } );

            $rootScope.$on( 'chart:unzoom', function () {
                if ( _self.changing ) return;

                $element.css( 'display', 'block' );
            } );

            $rootScope.$on( 'chart:zoom', function () {
                if ( _self.changing ) return;

                $element.css( 'display', 'none' );
            } );
        }],
    };
} );

angular.module( 'MarkOlbert.fullScreenToggle', [] ).directive( 'fullScreenToggle', function ($rootScope) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: '^^chartContainer',
        link: function(scope,element,attrs, chartCtrl){
            element.css('height', chartCtrl.chartHeight );

            $rootScope.$on( 'chart:zoom', function () {
                if ( !chartCtrl.changing ) return;

                element.css( 'height', 1000 );
            } );

            $rootScope.$on( 'chart:unzoom', function () {
                element.css( 'height', chartCtrl.chartHeight );
            } );
        },
    };
} );
```

In the bar-chart directive I have a simple watch, which should respond to changes in the bar-chart's height:

```
    scope.$watch( function () { return element.height(); }, function () {
        if ( element.height() == 0 ) return;
    }, true );
```

Right now it doesn't do anything, because I'm trying to figure out why it doesn't get called when full-screen-toggle changes the height.

The show/hide functionality works as designed. All the various event listeners in chart-container and full-screen-toggle are called when they should be, and execute without errors.

When chart-container changes the width of its element the page updates as expected. But when full-screen-toggle changes the bar-chart's height nothing happens. The $watch in bar-chart never fires.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.on()` is a jqLite/jQuery method and does not automatically trigger AngularJS' digest loop.

What happens now is:

1. Element is clicked on
2. Zoom or Unzoom is called
3. Element's CSS is changed
4. Event is broadcasted
5. Listeners for the broadcasted event are notified
6. Element's height is changed

But since the digest cycle was never triggered, the watcher that checks the element's height will never execute and no change will be detected.

You can use `$apply`:

```
$element.on('click', function() {
  $scope.$apply(function() {
    switch (zoomState) {
      case 'normal':
        zoom();
        break;

      case 'full':
        unZoom();
        break;
    }
  });
});
```